# Django Form with preview and confirmation

Tags: django, forms, validation, preview, confirmation

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner at Django.

I'm trying to create an app where I want the customer to preview and confirm a form before submitting it. I tried using the built-in Django FormPreview, but discovered that it didn't support File fields, so I threw it away.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concept idea would be:

In your template:

```
<input name='preview' type='submit' />
<input name='submit' type='submit' />
```

in the view to fetch your post:

```
form = YourFormName(request.POST)
if 'preview' in request.POST:
    # here you return the response you wish
    # the user to see when trying preview
    # for example form.is_valid()
    # could be nice to deal with
if 'submit' in request.POST:
    # normal form handling
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'd rather split it up into a few steps (because I'd like to design the preview step a little different). So a "Preview" button first, then a "submit" button in the second view. Any ideas?

Comment: You could display different buttons depending on the users session. If user previews the form, save that state in session and when rendering form you either draw preview or submit button.

Comment: splitting in different steps could also risk DRY as you would have to render the form in similar ways, multiple times.